# Error 1067- on start OpenSSH by net start opensshd in windows cmd

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh, sshd

I try to start opensshd app by following command line: net start opensshd but i encounter below message after press enter in CMD:

> ```
>  The OpenSSH Server service is starting.
>
> The OpenSSH Server service could not be started.
>
> A system error has occurred.
>
> System error 1067 has occurred.
>
> The process terminated unexpectedly.
> ```

i install openssh.
please Help Me!

Answer (score 38):

I got the similar problem that i cannot startup the "OpenSSH SSH Serve" service after following the instructions in https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-install-an-openssh-server-client-on-a-windows-2016-server/

I later on found out that this is the **security** problem in the C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host*key files. All the key files in this folder should **ONLY** be owned by following 2 system users:

1. BUILTIN\Administrators
2. NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

In the Powershell under the C:\ProgramData\ssh folder, issue following command can list out the owners of the file ssh_host_dsa_key:

```
 PS C:\ProgramData\ssh> icacls .\ssh_host_dsa_key
 .\ssh_host_dsa_key BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                    xxdomain\otheruser:(M)

 Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Obviously we need to remove the user "xxdomain\otheruser" from the owner list

**Resolution**

Updated on Nov 25, 2019: Found out that the OpenSSH-Win64.zip file already contained a powershell script: FixHostFilePermissions.ps1

What you need to do is to run following inside the powershell:

```
cd 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64'
.\FixHostFilePermissions.ps1
```

And press 'Enter' for each question to update the permission.

Answer (score 7):

just write this command in PowerShell

```
cd 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64'
.\FixHostFilePermissions.ps1
```

then press enter .

Answer (score 3):

I got this error, and it turned out in my case to be an error I'd made editing sshd_config, so be sure to check this. Spent ages trying to diagnose this.

Hope that saves someone some pain.

Comment: Your comment saved me so much time! I spent hours configuring policies and permissions as everybody suggests.

Comment: Thank you, this comment saved me hours of researching!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall old versions of OpenSSH Client & Server from Optional Features.
2. Remove `%ProgramData%\ssh` directory and its contents.
3. Install latest beta version of OpenSSH as explained here: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH

   - Using winget is the easiest way.
   - Run `winget uninstall "openssh beta"` to remove older version
   - `winget install "openssh beta"` to install latest version.
4. In an administrative command prompt, Navigate to `%ProgramFiles%\OpenSSH` and run both `FixHostFilePermissions.ps1` and `FixUserFilePermissions.ps1`. Answer all to `Y`(Yes) or `A`(All).
5. Try to start the OpenSSH service.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a permission issue.

Open a PowerShell in non-administrator mode. Run sshd.exe.

I finally see the proper error:

```
__PROGRAMDATA__\ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied
```

If you go into `services.msc` you can locate `OpenSSH SSH Server` and it has a place to specify which user to run it with.

Or you can fix the permissions of the `sshd_config` file.

Or maybe you have another issue.

The `.\FixHostFilePermissions.ps1` and `.\FixUserFilePermissions.ps1` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error by installing OpenSSH on Windows 7...

Open "***services.msc***" and try to start the service from there.

If it still doesn't work then you can try to follow the steps in this tutorial:
http://www.techpaste.com/2015/06/windows-ssh-server-setup-and-configuration/

**One important thing:** Try to download an older version of OpenSSH
Download Link: http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html#botpage 
(I recommend you the version "*setupssh-7.3p1-2*")

Hope it works 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to download and install an MSI from [this github repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32776669)

Comment: @user16217248 It's essentially a download link, there is nothing to add other than why this works.